# In what ways can the interpreter leave a class definition?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I'm intrigued by the following statement:

> When a class definition is left normally (via the end), a *class object* is created. *(from the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax))*

In what other ways can the class definition "be left"? I can think of a `SyntaxError`. Are there other ways?

Comment: Any other exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
>>> class A:
...     x = y
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in A
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Comment: Of course! I was thinking that anything inside the `class` block would only be executed when I actually built an instance of the class. But statements that are not function definitions get executed right away.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the phrase "When a class definition is left normally (via the end)" refers to how Python builds your object class definitions during the first phase of compilation.

Suppose you declare a class:

```
# <--- `Foo` is NOT defined as a class object in this context

class Foo:
  def say_hello(self):
    # Whatever
    pass

  # <--- Interpreter leaves class declaration here

# <--- `Foo` is now defined as a class object in this context

type(Foo)  # Returns `<type 'classobj'>`
```

Before you actually execute your program, the Python compiler does a pass through your code to build an index of object and class definitions that will be used as your program runs (often referred to as a "symbol table"). When it reaches `class Foo` it begins interpreting the following lines as the class definition for `Foo` until the last indented line is reached and the compiler at which point `Foo` is now a defined symbol in our index and Python goes on its way running the rest of your program.